# Help with a variant of a theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The original theorem states that

> Let $ϕ$ be continuous on $\Bbb{R}$, let $f$ be finite on $Ω$ a.e., then $ϕ∘f$ is measurable if $f$ is measurable.

Now is it true for a slightly different version? How to prove it? Thank you!

> Let $ϕ$ be continuous **a.e.** on $\Bbb{R}$, let $f$ be finite on $Ω$ a.e., then $ϕ∘f$ is measurable if $f$ is measurable.

---

The following might be helpful.

I know the proof of the original theorem, which I copy as the following,

> Since $ϕ$ is defined on $\Bbb{R}$ and is continuous, then $ϕ^{-1} (G)$ is an open set if $G$ is open, by Theorem 24. Now given any open set $G$, $(ϕ∘f)^{-1} (G)=f^{-1} (ϕ^{-1} (G))$ is measurable since $f$ is measurable and $ϕ^{-1} (G)$ is open, which gives $ϕ∘f$ is measurable.

Here the "Theorem 24" states

> If $f:Ω→R$ is a continuous function, then for any open set $G⊆R$, $f^{-1} (G)$ is open relative to $Ω$. In particular, when $\Omega = \Bbb{R}$, $f^{-1} (G)$ is open.

Another theorem used in the proof is that

> If $f$ is a measurable function and $G$ is open, then $f^{-1}(G) is measurable.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modified theorem is false. Say $C$ is the middle-thirds Cantor set. Let $K$ be a "fat Cantor set". There is a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(K)=C$. Now $K$ contains a non-measurable set $F$; let $E=f(F)$.

Let $\phi=\chi_E$.

Now $f$ is certainly measurable, being continuous. And $\phi$ is continuous almost everywhere, since it equals $0$ on $\mathbb R\setminus C$. But $\phi\circ f=\chi_F$, which is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

**Corollary of your last statement:** A function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $g^{-1}(B)$ is Lebesgue measurable for each Borel set $B$.

As David C. Ullrich said, the modification is false. It is mainly because there exists set that is Lebesgue measurable (having Lebesgue outer measure zero) but not Borel.

Lets call such set $A$, define $\phi = \chi_A$, then $\phi^{-1}(G)$ is not Borel thus $f^{-1}(\phi^{-1}(G))$ is not necessarily a Lebesgue measurable set.